# Is there a way to specify collection name for Java bean being stored into RavenDB?

Tags: java, ravendb, ravendb4

I'm using RavenDB with JAVA ravendb-jvm-client for my app, where existing collection names does'n reflect 'User.java' -> 'Users' convention. Is there a way how to specifiy correct collection name for java beans so java client use this instead of automatic convention? Something similar to @Table annotation for JPA.

I know I can specify collection name for example in queries e.g. `session.query(User.class, Query.collection("custUsers"));` ... but its very verbose to specify it repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `FindCollectionName` convention of the `DocumentStore`.

In Java, you can use `setFindCollectionName` of the conventions.

From https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/java/client-api/session/configuration/how-to-customize-collection-assignment-for-entities :

> By default a collection name is pluralized form of a name of an entity type. For example objects of type `Category` will belong to `Categories` collection. However if your intention is to classify them as `ProductGroups` use the following code:

```
store.getConventions().setFindCollectionName(clazz -> {
    if (Category.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        return "ProductGroups";
    }

    return DocumentConventions.defaultGetCollectionName(clazz);
});
```

Documentation on conventions in general: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/java/client-api/configuration/identifier-generation/global